# Archive old items in sharepoint using flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, archive, ms-flow

I have to created flow to move the past 30days items from sharepoint list to another new list as part of archiving. It is working as expected.

**Issue:**

- Will threshold level calculate for a new list?
- The flow not working for the old items i.e items created before flow implementation.

Provide some suggestion to move the items for old items as well

Answer (score 0):

The new list also has 5000 list view threshold.

Currently, there is no way to run a flow manually. You can refer to [it](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Flow/Start-Flow-on-List-Item/td-p/85087).

As a workaround, I suggest you create a schedule flow for your requirement.

[Run flows on a schedule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/run-scheduled-tasks)